# Fixing broken data source links in MXD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I've downloaded a data set from ESRI as part of EDN, and it contains world data in a folder such as this:

C:\Download\ESRI\EDN Data\DataMapsArcGIS2013_1\world\World Map.mxd

When I double-click this .mxd file, it opens up in ArcGIS 10.2, but nearly all of the data source links are broken. How can I fix these links? What is the data source for this map?

Comment: A picture of whatever is on the Source tab of the Layer Properties for one of these broken layers would help here.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that you downloaded/unzipped/etc the accompanying data.

Then, to expand on what @Hornbydd is pointing you towards, you can set the correct data source as detailed in [Repairing broken data links](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000020000000). Basically, you have to select each broken layer and navigate to the actual location of the data source.

Also, if you are familiar with Python (or want to start learning!), you can use arcpy to fix several layers at the same time, as long as they are in the same workspace: [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Updating_and_fixing_data_sources_with_arcpy_mapping/00s30000004p000000/)

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug in 10.2 but the Set Data Source dialog in ArcMap (which allows file types of "Feature classes") does not allow me to select any of the files in the folder where the .sdc files eveidently exist. I have lost days of work trying to get this to work. The European data works fine; something is broken in the world map data.

Comment: @Dean Do the feature classes/tables you are trying to find show up if you browse to that location in catalog? You should be able to see the contents of the SDC. If not then something is wrong with the data, not the map.

Comment: All I see is the gray background of the continents. The European Thematic Maps.mxd shows me a whole load more features in the preview in ArcCatalog. For World Map.mxd I get just the continents.  Same if I click in the data folders of the world and of europe: I see all the details in europe for the .lyr and for the .sdc files, but for the world maps it just says "This selection cannot be previewed".

Comment: @Dean The symptoms you describe here seem to be related to your data sources being *.sdc files but your question does not mention that.  Please edit your question to provide a more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open help and type "[repair data sources](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000020000000)", you get a whole page about how to repair broken links.

Comment: I have tried that. The point I am trying to make is that the dialog that sets the data source doesn't list any data sources, though they clearly exist if I check in windows explorer. It's as if the dialog is broken or the file type is set up wrong somehow.